# Lightning Component does't send any email

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I can`t solve the following problem. I have a custom object with several fields. One of them have Lookup on Contact. And in my component I try to send email with the rich-text from record to email address linking with Contact, but nothing happen:

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" access="global">

   <aura:attribute name="record" type="Rotation__c" default="{ 'sobjectType' : 'Rotation__c' }"/>

    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />


 </aura:if>
  </div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
   openModel: function(component, event, helper) {
      // for Display Model,set the "isOpen" attribute to "true"
      component.set("v.isOpen", true);
   },

   closeModel: function(component, event, helper) {
      // for Hide/Close Model,set the "isOpen" attribute to "Fasle"  
      component.set("v.isOpen", false);
   },

    handleSubmit:function(component,event, helper){
      event.preventDefault();
      var eventFields = event.getParam("fields");
      component.find('editForm').submit(eventFields);
      //var result = component.find("editForm").submit();
       component.set("v.isOpen", false);
  },

   handleSuccess :function(component, helper) {
      var homeEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
      homeEvt.setParams({
          "recordId": component.get("v.recordId")
      });
      homeEvt.fire();     
  },




})
```

Helper

```
({
 sendHelper: function(component,event,helper, getEmail, getSubject, getbody, getrecordid) {
        console.log('helperrecid'+getrecordid);
        // call the server side controller method   
        var action = component.get("c.sendMailMethod");
        // set the 3 params to sendMailMethod method 
        action.setParams({
            'mMail': getEmail,
            'mSubject': getSubject,
            'mbody': getbody,
            'recid':getrecordid
        });


        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
})
```

Any ideas?

**Updated. Controller method**

```
   public static void sendMailMethod(String mMail ,String mSubject ,String mbody,string recordId){

        //Inserting the record id in Email subject
        string subrec= '('+ recordId +')';  
        // For storing Relation Id
        string opcid ='';
        //Email Sending Start
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails =  new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();  
        //Create a new Email
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();        
        //Set list of people who should get the email        
        List<String> sendTo = mMail.split(',');
        //Setting Senders
        mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);        
        String addrUrl='e62ubs9wkx9ma0e6akh8qbbwtli5o6hpjy.7f-4wpbcua2.ap5.apex.salesforce.com';




}
```

Comment: What does your Apex controller do to send the email?

Comment: My post updated.

Comment: You are catching and swallowing and exception. What exception do your logs say is being thrown?

Answer (score 2):

You are populating the parameters of your Apex controller method incorrectly.

```
    action.setParams({
        'mMail': getEmail,
        'mSubject': getSubject,
        'mbody': getbody,
        'recid':getrecordid
    });
```

The signature of the server method is

```
public static void sendMailMethod(String mMail ,String mSubject ,String mbody,string recordId){
```

The final parameter's name is `recordId`, not `recid`.

This probably causes a `NullPointerException` here

```
        if(recordId.startsWith('003')){
```

which you never know about because your exception handler does not meaningfully surface exceptions to you:

```
    catch(Exception e){
        System.debug('Queryue: ' + e);
    }
```

I'd strongly recommend not using this exception handler pattern. During development, it will result in inexplicable behavior because you are not seeing the consequences of your own mistakes. In production, it silently hides issues that occur, which can impact data integrity and result in you not being aware of serious production problems.

### Update

The new version of your Apex server controller method does not call `Messaging.sendEmail()`. You must explicitly perform an email send in order for the message to be sent.

Comment: Thank you sir. After update In this case i just get nothing. After click on button Email page with component just freeze for a little bit and that`s all. Let me just explain my logic one more time. After clicking on the component, I get a modal box, then I just want to click on the Email button without entering the any address (the address is Contact.Email related to this record) My rich text edit should be the body of the letter, but the data from my record should be stored in it. Please tell me I'm going in the right direction? Or I need code changes?

Comment: I can't tell you from that description what is wrong. You need to look at your Apex logs and your JavaScript console, maybe even adding some log statements, to see what your code is doing. If you have any exception handlers, I would comment them out until you're finished debugging.

Comment: Found one more issue - link between Payment__c and bodytext. And now it looks like: 
<lightning:inputRichText value="{!v.record.Payment__c}"/>
 var getbody = component.get("v.record.Payment__c");

But it still no use. I think i need auto populated adress field in my component. Do you have some examples or any thoughts how can i solve it?

Comment: Hey Bjørn, I'm happy to try to help but since I don't have your code in my org you'll have to do the heavy lifting of figuring out *what* the problem is. (SFSE works well on [specific questions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)). If you have a separate issue from the one above, you may want to do some debugging to pin down exactly what is going wrong and open a new question.